# how to set box-shadow to an animated box in css Without changing the angle of the shadow

Tags: css, css-animations

I create a box that has rotate animation ***but when I use box-shadow for it, the shadow is turned with the box too.***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <style>
  body{
   display:flex;}
  .boxes{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: -15px 15px 15px 2px #111111;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 6%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 10%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
    margin:0 2rem;
}
  #box2{
    animation: rot 4s alternate infinite -.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  @keyframes rot {
    from {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(-45deg);
    }
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box1" class="boxes"></div>
  <div id="box2" class="boxes"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

***( I do not want the shadow to *rotate with the box* )***

Answer (score 0):

you need also to rest the offsets value of the box-shadow while rotate() is being modified

average example of the idea, from there , tune the offsets values of box-shadow so it seems not moving.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .boxes {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: -15px 15px 15px 2px #111111;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 6%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 10%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
      margin: 0 2rem;
    }
    
    #box2 {
      animation: rot 4s alternate infinite -.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    @keyframes rot {
      from {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        
      box-shadow: -0px 15px 15px 2px #111111;
      }
      to {
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        
      box-shadow: -15px 0px 15px 2px #111111;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box1" class="boxes"></div>
  <div id="box2" class="boxes"></div>
</body>

</html>
```